# How to retrieve return value from $.post function

Tags: jquery

as my subject / title. here is my code

```
$(document).on("keyup","[name=BNAM]",function(){
    var nam = $(this).attr("name");
    var val = $(this).val();
    var typ = $(this).prev().val();

    $.post(
        "pro/bulletins_handle.php",
        {BTN:"QCHKNAM",BTYP:typ,BNAM:val},
        function(data){ 
        alert(nam+":"+val+":"+data); //display to check the return value of data
        var reTURN = data; //assign data into reTURN
            alert($(this).html());//Error: it say undefined
        });
    alert(reTURN); //Error: reTURN is not defined
});
```

** my return from post is 0 or 1 **

---

Questions:
1). How to retrieve return value from $.post function?
2). Why it say undefined? $(this) is not = [name=BNAM] ??

Comment: May I ask why you name your variables, `reTURN` in particular, like that?

Comment: two js run like `$.post` then `alert(reTURN)` , while `var reTURN = data ` was executed after post succuess and callback ..

Comment: thordarson
reTURN is use to hold value of data, which i wish to use outside the post later. if data is 0 then reTURN will be 0, if data is 1 then reTURN will be 1. Just simple as that

Comment: :farmer1992: 
not really understand your suggestion/comments

Comment: @user1493339 I know what it does, I was just curious about your weird capitalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to move the line with `alert(reTURN);` up and into the function(data) block. The code within this function will execute when the data is successfully loaded. The code below (even though it is below) will execute before the data is ready, becase of js' asynchronous nature.

Also, the this variable you're using within your $.post block does not mean what you think. This code should work better:

```
$(document).on("keyup","[name=BNAM]",function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var nam = $this.attr("name");
    var val = $this.val();
    var typ = $this.prev().val();

    $.post(
        "pro/bulletins_handle.php",
        {BTN:"QCHKNAM",BTYP:typ,BNAM:val},
        function(data){ 
            alert(nam+":"+val+":"+data); //display to check the return value of data
            alert($this.html());
            alert(data);
        });    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

### 1

All ajax requests (including `$.post`) execute *asynchronously*.  This means that any part of the code that may be after the request but outside the callback will most likely execute *before* the ajax requests completes, and you cannot depend on access to that data.

If you want to use the data, you must use it in the callback to the ajax request.

### 2

`this` in the context above is a jQuery XMLHttpRequest object, not a `DOM` element.  It does not have an `html` method.  Do something like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '[name=BNAM]', function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   //$this is now available as the DOM element in the ajax callback
```

Comment: after your {var $this = $(this);}

i add {alert($this)}

and it return me {[object Object]}, so what it means? and how to i get the attribute of it?

Comment: @user1493339 use `console.log` not alert.  What attribute do you want?

Comment: [Explosion Pills] if the return is 0 then i wish to bold the input[name=BNAM], * i need to use this coz they is few input[name=BNAM] in the page (auto generate, depend on database). i know it work fine if there is ONLY 1 input[name=BNAM] within the page

Comment: `$this.css('font-weight', 'bold')`

Comment: [Explosion Pills] it return undefined. [var $this = $(this);
   var x = $this.attr("name");
   alert(x);]

Comment: @user1493339 when are you doing `$this.attr('name')`?  That should work.